# Difference between 'enumType' and 'TEnum'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msdn

Guy new to C# here. I was looking around MSDN skimming through `enum` methods, but I could not tell the difference between `TEnum` and `enumType`.

```
public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(
string value,
out TEnum result)

public static string[] GetNames(
Type enumType)
```

What is the difference here? For the first method, wouldn't it possibly be better to return `enumType result` instead?

Comment: Read up on Generics in DOT NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Enum.GetNames() was supported all the way back to .NET 1.0, basic reason it doesn't use generics.  You need at least 4.0 to use that TryParse() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TEnum is the Generic type of enumeration. You can pass any of your enumeration to that method.

The second method is a non-generic one, where you would use a **typeof** keyword to identify the enums and return the enum names as a string collection

Answer (score 3):

In `TryParse<TEnum>()` is a [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) method and `TEnum` is the generic type parameter.  Any time you see a method, class, or interface declaration followed by a name in angle brackets you have a generic type.  Generics are used to provide compile time type checks and improve performance by specifying the type the method is to use.

`GetNames` takes a [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) object.  A particular Type object represents particular class, interface, or enum.  It's probably better to compare to [Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static Object Parse(
    Type enumType,
    string value
);
```

Notice that `Enum.Parse` returns an `object`, which will require a cast to `TEnum`.

Generics where not added until .Net 2.0 so you will see a number of methods that have a generic version and a generic version that takes a `Type` object.  The non-generic versions are also useful when working with [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The first example is a [generic declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx). Typically, you usually only see it as `T`, but the author of that code wanted to denote that it should be an enum.

In your second example, `enumType` is just a variable name. The two methods do completely different things, and the two pieces you're looking at serve completely different purposes.